# Adding relative links in php includes files?

Tags: php, include, include-path, php-include

I have a structure like:

```
root/
  directory/
    index.php
    includes/
      header.html
    css/
      style.css
    pages/
      somefile.php
      somefile2.php
```

All three files (index.php, somefile.php, and somefile2.php) includes the header.html. The header.html has the relative link to the css. Since I'm not a pro at php, I don't know how to set this path so that it will work in all three pages. I've seen somewhere it says I must define the php path, but that this is set to the root/ instead of root/directory/ as in www.mysite.com/directory/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution would be to add the following line to your header:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Then all of your relative paths will start from the root directory. The alternative is to update all of your relative paths corresponding to their location in the directory hierarchy. Something like:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dir1/dir2/page.html'

// or...

'../../page.html'
```